# Xcode7 iOS 9 can't make View native size

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, layout, size

I have a project. A newly created one. It has LaunchScreen.storyboard. After view is loaded, application each second writes to a console its View Size (self.view.bounds.size).
I started it in iPhone 6 Simulator. Result - 667x375. Why not a native 2x size?

I decided that LaunchScreen is not enough. I set "Launch Images Source" to "LaunchImage" asset, where I put correct Retina HD 5.5 and Retina HD 4.7 screens.
Result - 667x375.

I tried editing info.plist manually and putting "Default-xxxh@2x.png" files in same folder where Info.plist is. Same situation.

I tried setting LaunchScreen to my Main,storyboard. Same situation.

(Same happens with iPhone 5 device which I use for testing - size is always 568x320).

Please help.

I am in despair...

Comment: Bounds is in _points_, not pixels. Try `-[UIScreen nativeBounds]` if you want the number of pixels. You should know, though, that bounds is what you should be using for nearly all practical purposes.

Comment: @BenPious Thank you! That is totally correct.